# Trouble in uploading profile image to parse.com during signUpInBackgroundWithBlock

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiimage

I am using the code below to sign up a user with username, password, and a profile picture.

```
func createUserwithAllFields() {
    let profileImageData =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileAvatar.image, 0.6)
    //let profileImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImg, 0.6)
    let profileImageFile = PFFile(data: profileImageData)


    if tv_username.text != ""
        && tv_password.text != ""
    {

        var user = PFUser()

        user.username = tv_username.text
        user.password = tv_password.text

        user["profileImage"] = profileImageFile

        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

                //if SignUp is successful

                let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
                installation["user"] = user
                installation.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)

                //self.showChatOverview()

                self.goToMainScreen()

            } else {

            }
        })

    }else{

    }
}
```

When I look at he `User` class on parse.com there is a file that get's uploaded (see screenshot below)
[image]

Although there is a file, when I click on it and download it, I open it to find a blank (i.e. white) image.

The `profileAvatar` is a `UIImageView` in the ViewController and it does point to a valid image because I can see that when I run the app.

This is the blank image that I see:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In parse you need to first save the user and after save the image, I modify your code to accomplish that:

```
func createUserwithAllFields() {
    let profileImageData =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileAvatar.image, 0.6)
    let profileImageFile = PFFile(data: profileImageData)
    if tv_username.text != "" && tv_password.text != "" {
        var user = PFUser()
        user.username = tv_username.text
        user.password = tv_password.text

        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                /println("SignUp is successful")
                 user["profileImage"] = profileImageFile
                 user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
                     if error == nil {
                         println("Image Saved")
                     } else {
                         println("Fail to Save Image")
                     }
                )}
            } else {
                println("Fail to Sign up")
            }
        })
    }else{
        println("Invalid username and password")
    }
}
```

Comment: tried that. If tried your modified code, no file gets uploaded for `profileImage` field.

Comment: How big is your image?

Comment: 10 kB (size of the image)

Comment: I am wondering if you are not allowed to create image in the user table, I am trying to find something in the Parse.com documentation but no luck!

Comment: So I found something - I tried a `*.jpg` image and that works perfectly. I was earlier trying a '*.png' and apparently that was the problem. Not sure why.

Comment: that is because you are using UIImageJPEGRepresentation, what is profileAvatar.image is it an UIImage?

Comment: profileAvatar is a UIImageView. What should I use instead of UIImageJPEGRepresentation if the actual images are ong files or do i need to convert them all to png?

Comment: When you uploading to parse try to use this "let imageFile = PFFile(name:"image.png", data:imageData)"

Comment: That's ok, I will convert my images to jpg because these images are asigned to certain UIImageViews in the Storyboard itself so I am not really getting the images with a name in the swift code.

Comment: Cool, I will have a look into it later on because got me curious, I will post the results here :) Good luck with your app!