# How to store PNG images for profile pictures on Parse.com?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, uiimage

I am using the code below to sign up a user with username, password, and a profile picture. WHen the profile picture is a `JPG` it works but **NOT** when the format is 'PNG`. WHen I upload a png image, the image is blank.

I think `JPG` is working because I am using this function `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`.

What should I be using for PNG?

Background: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30746277/trouble-in-uploading-profile-image-to-parse-com-during-signupinbackgroundwithblo)

```
func createUserwithAllFields() {
let profileImageData =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileAvatar.image, 0.6)
//let profileImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImg, 0.6)
let profileImageFile = PFFile(data: profileImageData)


if tv_username.text != ""
    && tv_password.text != ""
{

    var user = PFUser()

    user.username = tv_username.text
    user.password = tv_password.text

    user["profileImage"] = profileImageFile

    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            //if SignUp is successful

            let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
            installation["user"] = user
            installation.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)

            //self.showChatOverview()

            self.goToMainScreen()

        } else {

        }
    })

}else{

}
}
```

Comment: I got curious about it the other day, and I was able to make it work using the solution I post!

Comment: @Icaro sweet... seems obvious now should have searched. Will give it a try before i hit the sack.

Comment: Obvious now that we know, took me a long time to figure out first time!

Comment: Did it work for you? Let me know how it go and please don't forget to mark the answer as resolved if it did :) Thanks

Comment: @Icaro yep it worked, thanks. marked your answer as the answer, it was first.

Comment: Great news! Good luck with the rest of your app!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `UIImagePNGRepresentation` instead `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` that should fix it!

```
let profileImageData =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(profileAvatar.image, 0.6)
```

I hope that helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You said you want to save PNG image but you are using this:

```
let profileImageData =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileAvatar.image, 0.6)
```

`UIImageJPEGRepresentation` is not for saving png image. use `UIImagePNGRepresentation`.